# Storing files on OneDrive permanently

Tags: onedrive, microsoft-onedrive

If I understand it correctly, OneDrive is basically mirroring files/folders on my computer -- at least the ones that I tell it to. So, if I delete a synced file from computer, it will "eventually" be deleted from OneDrive as well.

Is there a way for me to create folders on OneDrive that will never be removed. These folders don't need to mirror any folder structure on my computer. I want to create a section on OneDrive where I can store files/folders permanently and I don't need to have copies of them on my computer. So, I'm happy to login to OneDrive using my browser or the app to upload files into this section.

Is this possible or will OneDrive always mirror my computer?

Answer (score 0):

You can simply choose not to synchonise a particular folder with your computer.

From [Choose which OneDrive folders to sync to your computer](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/choose-which-onedrive-folders-to-sync-to-your-computer-98b8b011-8b94-419b-aa95-a14ff2415e85)

> 1. Open **OneDrive settings** (select the OneDrive cloud icon in your notification area, and then select the OneDrive Help and Settings icon ⚙️ then Settings.)
> 2. Go to the **Account** tab.
> 3. Select **Choose folders**.
>
>    In the **Sync your OneDrive files to this PC** dialog box, uncheck any folders you don't want to sync to your computer and select **OK**.
>
>    [image]

You can create the folders on your computer, wait for them to upload and then turn on or off the synchronisation of that folder.

Once set up you would then log in to OneDrive using the Web interface and upload files to that directory. Files uploaded to this directory would then not be downloaded to your computer and so would not be easily deletable by that computer.

You would have to repeat this process on every computer you did not want to see this folder on.

Comment: How does not synchronizing a folder make it exist permanently on OneDrive?

Comment: @Ramhound It makes it unable to be deleted on the local computer, which fulfils the requirement of OP that he put something in the cloud and not be able to remove it on the local computer. They also say "These folders don't need to mirror any folder structure on my computer" which, once uploaded and then synchronisation turned off for that folder is pretty much fulfilled.